# How to define a few addresses in HOME_NET in suricata.yml?

Tags: security, suricata

I am trying to configure suricata in my network. When I set one `HOME_NET` in `/etc/suricata/suricata.yml` as :

```
HOME_NET: "[172.20.5.0/24]"
```

everything works fine. But when I try to define more than one pool of addresses as:

```
 HOME_NET: "[172.20.5.0/24,172.16.0.0/16,172.20.1.0/24]"
```

I cannot observe any events in `/var/log/suricata/log.fast`.

How to properly define a few networks in `HOME_NET` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to ping and **Home_Net**(172.20.5.12) from a **Home_Net**(172.20.5.18). And the property **External_Net** was set as **!$Home_Net**. The rule triggering ping alert:

> alert icmp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"GPL ICMP_INFO PING
>   *NIX"; itype:8; content:"|10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F|"; depth:32; classtype:misc-activity; sid:2100366; rev:8;
>   metadata:created_at 2010_09_23, updated_at 2010_09_23;)

Alerts only from **EXTERNAL_NET** to **HOME_NET** and I was pinging from **HOME_NET** to **HOME_NET**.

To see this "internal" ping alerts you need to define  **EXTERNAL_NET** as **any**.